What it means if "of " comes before a sentence?
I have found this in Sherlock Holmes A Study in Scarlet.
"Of contemporary literature, philosophy and politics he appeared to know next to nothing"
What is it mean by putting "Of" before this sentence?

It's fine, formal and used for emphasis. Also, somewhat old fashioned. Found in novels. [correction: What does putting of at the beginning mean?]

"He appeared to know next to nothing of [those subjects]." Inverted for emphasis, as Lambie says.

Of gin, my mother is very fond. To soap and water, my nephew aged 11 is allergic.

@MichaelHarvey How does he feel about bathtub gin?

Short answer: Although changes in word order sometimes go along with changes in meaning ("I am happy"/"Am I happy?"), in this case it has little change in meaning.

Its a reordering of a sentence which might more typically be phrased like:
He appeared to know next to nothing of [about] contemporary literature, philosophy and politics
Moving the prepositional phrase to the front of the sentence changes the emphasis.  Because we tend to focus on what we hear first, phrasing the sentence like this emphasizes the things he didn't know about (literature, philosophy, politics).  In the more typical phrasing, there's more emphasis on the character not knowing something.
Some prepositional phrases are commonly moved to the front of sentences, but others are not.  For example, these sentences that start with prepositional phrases sound natural, in writing, or in conversation:

After lunch I took a nap
From now on I'm only starting sentences with prepositional phrases
During the meeting Bob started to fall asleep

Note that all of these prepositions have to do with time
These sentences are also natural, but more are perhaps common in writing than in speech:

Except for cheesecake, you should never mix cheese and cake
By reducing the work hours of our team, we managed to improve moral and performance
Against all odds, they won

But some prepositional phrases sound stilted, overly formal, overly literary, or old-fashioned and should be avoided (unless part of a cliché or fixed phrase:

About economics I have no idea
Of spiders I am very afraid
In God we trust*

That last one is actually heard, because it's an idiom, but don't try the same structure with other words.  This would sound ridiculous:

In your ability to deliver this project on time I trust.

It's hard to find a strong pattern in the natural, somewhat formal and stilted uses.  One rule to follow is don't invert phrasal verbs.  The examples on this last list doen't even sound old-fashioned, they sound ludicrous:

Off his head was cut
Apart into a million pieces the puzzle fell
Quick! After the thief you have to go


Yoda from Star Wars has a lot to answer for with his reverse language! By the way, a great answer, thoroughly explored and well laid out.

Thank you for kindly explanation
